# Write to a text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I am looking for a way to write to a text file in C#.
I have created a form that has a textbox for firstname, lastname, phone number, date of birth.
When a user hits the button I would like that info wrote out to a text file. The examples I have found don't really tell me how. So that's why I am asking on here.

Comment: Lotsa examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z2ck8eh.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The very simplest way is just to use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx). Build the text into a single string however you want to, then use

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, text);
```

Alternatively you can open a `TextWriter` on the file to do it bit by bit:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filename)) // Or AppendText
{
    writer.WriteLine("First name: {0}", firstNameInput.Text);
    writer.WriteLine("Last name: {0}", lastNameInput.Text);
    writer.WriteLine("Phone number: {0}", phoneInput.Text);
    writer.WriteLine("Date of birth: {0}", birthInput.Text);
}
```

Note that you may want to be more cunning about the date of birth than just dumping the text directly from the user - you may want to validate it and write it in a standard format, for example.

Comment: CreateText would like a filename

Comment: @Henk: Done, thanks. (Was the -1 for that? If not, comments on the downvote very welcome...)

Answer (score 2):

Inside a ButtonClick or similar:

```
using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText(fileName))
{
    writer.WriteLine(firstNametextbox.Text);
    // other writes
}
```