# Writing Output to A File in C# 2005

Tags: c#

i have created a marksheet program in c# 2005, its working fine it is taking input and showing the output by using the below code. now if i want that the output of this program is also copied in a new file located in my C or any drive. what should i do? i tried IO.StreamWriter but its not working.

```
using(System.IO.TextWriter writer = System.IO.File.CreateText(@"C:\1.txt"))
        {
Console.WriteLine("\t\tMarksheet - Prislogix Public School");
                Console.Write("\n\nStudent Name : " + name);
                Console.Write("\nClass : " + cls);
                Console.Write("\nRoll Number : " + roll);
                Console.Write("\n\nSubject\t\tObtained Marks\t\tTotal Marks");
                Console.Write("\n\nChemistry\t\t" + chem + "\t\t75");
                Console.Write("\nEnglish\t\t\t" + eng + "\t\t100");
                Console.Write("\nCalculus\t\t\t" + urd + "\t\t100");
                Console.Write("\nDiscrete\t\t\t" + sin + "\t\t75");
                Console.Write("\nMathematics\t\t" + mat + "\t\t100");
                Console.Write("\nPhysics\t\t\t" + phy + "\t\t75");
                Console.Write("\nComputer\t\t" + comp + "\t\t100");
                Console.Write("\nMethods\t\t" + isl + "\t\t50");
                float tot = chem + eng + urd + sin + mat + phy + comp + isl;
                Console.Write("\n\n\t\t\tTotal Obtained Marks : " + tot + "\tOut Of 625");
                float per;
                per = (tot / 625) * 100;
                Console.Write("\n\t\t\tPercentage : " + per + "%");
                if (per < 49 && per > 40)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tFAILED!");
                }
                if (per <= 59 && per >= 50)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tGrade : C");
                }
                if (per <= 69 && per >= 60)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tGrade : B");
                }
                if (per <= 79 && per >= 70)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tGrade : A");
                }
                if (per <= 89 && per >= 80)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tGrade : A+");
                }
                if (per <= 100 && per >= 90)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tGrade : A-ONE");
                }
            }
}
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write to a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138779/how-to-write-to-a-text-file)

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Is there an error? You have to call `Close()` on the writer when you're done with it, or put it into a using block.

Comment: The code you have posted has a closing `}` with no opening `{`. Can you post the code where you say you try to use a `StreamWriter`?

Comment: You may also need to call `Flush()`...

Comment: @El Ronnoco: Not if he's doing it right and uses `using`.

Answer (score 2):

`StreamWriter` *does* work. It's a shame you haven't shown us your attempt at using it.

The simplest way of *creating* a `StreamWriter` to write to a file is to use [`File.CreateText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx). Then you should be able to use `StreamWriter.Write` in the same way as `Console.Write`. Don't forget to use a `using` statement:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("..."))
{
    // Write stuff here
}
```

That makes sure the writer will be disposed at the end of the `using` statement, which will flush and close the file.

If you want to write to *both* the console and the file, you may want a "tee" `TextWriter` which writes to two outputs... or you could just look at the file after running the program.

One thing to note: in Windows, the normal line ending is `\r\n` rather than just `\n`. If the problem was just that all the output looked like it was on one line in Notepad, that's probably the issue. Consider using `WriteLine` instead of `Write`, to write out the platform default line terminator at the end of the line.

If all of this fails, please tell us what's going wrong with rather more detail than "it's not working".

Comment: @Aliza: Please update your question with the *actual* code you tried.

Comment: i pasted all my given code which is to be printed in using (textwriter.....) { } but still my given file is empty

Comment: @Aliza: You didn't change any of the code to actually *use* `writer` though - it's still just calling `Console.Write`.

Comment: @Jon its working now but the output is not showing in console.. what should i do to show output on console and text file both?

Comment: @Aliza: I covered this in my answer - or you can use Rune's answer.

Comment: @Aliza: C# is case sensitive - it's StringBuilder, not Stringbuilder.

Comment: @Aliza: *Please* read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. "It's not working" gives us no information. StringBuilder definitely *does* exist in System.Text.

Comment: actually stringbuilder is entered but when pressing (.) there are just two entries Equals & Reference. in Rune's answer there is StringBuilder.ToString() but its wrong

Comment: @Aliza: No, Rune's code is not wrong. My guess is that you haven't declared a variable called `stringBuilder` of type `StringBuilder`. It looks like you're *very* new to C#... and while Stack Overflow is great, it's not really the right place to learn the absolute basics. I *strongly* recommend that you get an introductory C# book.

Comment: well i tried it, its working in the console but its not writing to my file. what i write is

Comment: StringBuilder a;
a = new StringBuilder();
after all calls i put this

Comment: @Aliza: It's still not at all clear what your code looks like or exactly what the result is.

Answer (score 1):

Change all calls to Console.Write so that they write to a StringBuilder instance instead. After the printing is done you can do the following:

```
Console.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("your path here", stringBuilder.ToString());
```

This will probably be the easiest fix. It will still write the output to the Console, but it will also write to the file you want.

Comment: System.Text.StringBuilder is a buffer for building large strings. It is very fast to write to and allows you to extract the string afterwards using ToString. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

Comment: My reply may be a bit confusing. It is not a static class so you must create an instance of it: System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();